# Order by number in nvarchar

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, sql-order-by

I have an `nvarchar` column which I am trying to order by in the following query:

```
select youngestage
from table1 
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(youngestage) = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
    , CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(youngestage) = 1 THEN CAST(youngestage AS INT) ELSE 0 END
    , youngestage
```

Results

```
 0
 1
 1.5
 10
 11
 12
 14
 2
 3
```

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value ' 1.5' to data type int.

How can I order like this

```
YoungestAge
 0
 1
 1.5
 2
 3
10
11
12
14
```

Comment: Try converting to Float instead of Int.

Comment: but why are you converting to `int` when it seems you need a `decimal` or a `float`?

Comment: Use [`numeric`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) instead. Do you need to have ***same*** conditions in your `CASE` clause?

Comment: Yay, FLOAT is working. Not sure why ISNUMERIC wont work. How do I give you credit?

Comment: `ISNUMERIC` is working though, `1.5` can be converted to a number...just not to an `int`

Comment: Your function call works - your CAST is a problem.

Comment: [Stop using ISNUMERIC, it’s (probably) wrong](https://wp.larnu.uk/stop-using-isnumeric-its-probably-wrong/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `try_cast()`.  I would recommend:

```
ORDER BY TRY_CONVERT(numeric(20, 1), youngestage)
```

Comment: It works as well. Thank you. I'm trying give credit to LANMARK but not sure how

Comment: @user13570703 . . . As the OP you can accept one of the answers (this one was first).  You don't  have enough reputation to upvote the answers.

Answer (score 0):

You have decimal values, so you should cast them to `decimal` (or `numeric` for example) rather than `int`.

This should do what you want:

```
order by cast(youngestage as decimal(10, 5))
```

You might need to adapt the size and precision of the datatype to your actual use case.

If some of your values can't be cast to decimal, you can also use `try_cast()` to avoid conversion errors:

```
order by try_cast(youngestage as decimal(10, 5))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CAST` function to convert the **NVARCHAR** data type to **Decimal** in your Order by Clause.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(
Youngestage NVARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT INTO @T VALUES('0')
INSERT INTO @T VALUES('1')
INSERT INTO @T VALUES('1.5')
INSERT INTO @T VALUES('10')
INSERT INTO @T VALUES('11')
INSERT INTO @T VALUES('12')
INSERT INTO @T VALUES('14')
INSERT INTO @T VALUES('2')
INSERT INTO @T VALUES('3')
```

Main Query:

```
SELECT * FROM @T 
ORDER BY CAST(Youngestage as decimal(10,2))
```